# SQL Server : update table by using when then and using order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Trying to update sub-priority based on priority, if priority is 1 then all sub-priorities should increment by +1 based on priority where order also needed while updating the sub-priority

I have tried the below query in MySql it's working as expected, but the same query is not working in SQL Server; the expression that I have used in `THEN` condition is not working in SQL Server.

```
SET @p1=0;
SET @p2=0;
SET @P3=0;

UPDATE line_distro_dtl 
SET dc_sub_priority = 
    CASE 
        WHEN (dc_priority =1) THEN (select @p1 := @p1 + 1)
        WHEN (dc_priority =2) THEN (select @p2 := @p2 + 1) 
        WHEN (dc_priority =3) THEN (select @p3 := @p3 + 1) 
    END
WHERE dc_number = 6336 
ORDER BY dc_priority ASC, future_sales DESC;
```

In SQL Server, I have declare `@p1`, because of we must declare scalar variables:

```
Declare @p1 int;
Declare @p2 int;
Declare @p3 int;
SET @p1=0;
SET @p2=0;
SET @P3=0;
```

How to achieve the above query in SQL Server 2019?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ld.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dc_priority order by future_sales desc) as seqnum
      from line_distro_dtl
      where dc_number = 6336
     )
update toupdate
    set dc_sub_priority = seqnum;
```

This assigns a sequential number to the sub priority for `6336` for each priority.

Comment: perfect, thx you Gordon, its very helpful your solution is working for me.